# ATtiny85, ARduino IDE, TinyDebug: Error sending int values

Tags: arduino, serial, attiny

The setup:

An ATtiny85 is programmed using the Arduino IDE, it is supposed to read the ambient light from an LDR and turn on/off an LED accordingly. To get a better understanding of what my sensor readings are in different lighting situations I'd like to send the reading to my serial console using `TinyDebug`, a part of the Arduino-on-ATtiny libraries.

Here's the minimum sketch:

```
String myString;

void setup() {
  pinMode(0, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  int sensorValue = analogRead(2);
  String myString = String(sensorValue);
  Serial.write(sensorValue);
  Serial.write("\n\r");

  if (sensorValue > 500) {
    digitalWrite(0, HIGH);
  }
  else {
    digitalWrite(0, LOW);
  }

  delay(500);
}
```

On my serial console all I receive is garbage:

```
l

x



x

l

{



t

n

z



u

l

|



q

m





n

o
(...)
```

Changing the codes `Serial.write(sensorValue);` to `Serial.write("hello");` nicely prints out

```
hello
hello
hello
(...)
```

so I suppose the serial communication itself works.

Trying to convert the `int` value to a string and sending that string, ie `Serial.write(myString);` gives a compiler error:

```
(...)
sketch_may24b.ino: In function 'void loop()':
sketch_may24b:11: error: no matching function for call to 'TinyDebugSerial::write(String&)'
/Users/cts/Documents/Arduino/hardware/tiny/cores/tiny/TinyDebugSerial.h:728: note: candidates are: virtual size_t TinyDebugSerial::write(uint8_t)
/Users/cts/Documents/Arduino/hardware/tiny/cores/tiny/Print.h:75: note:                 virtual void Print::write(const uint8_t*, size_t)
/Users/cts/Documents/Arduino/hardware/tiny/cores/tiny/Print.h:74: note:                 virtual void Print::write(const char*)
```

Any idea how I can send my sensor values to my serial console instead?

Comment: For reference: [String();](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringConstructor)

Comment: Is [`utoa();`](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__stdlib.html#ga5816f25bd0f45787cc16bebf6a735d8a) an option as alternative for `String(sensorValue);`? It does require you to declare a buffer beforehand though. Some libraries or functions are not supported on ATtiny, but it is not described which exact ones. Trial and error is proposed.

Comment: Why are you first converting the integer to a string: `String myString = String(sensorValue);` only to try and print the integer itself on the next line: `Serial.write(sensorValue);` ?

Comment: @jippie - Don't you mean `Serial.write(&sensorValue);`? Or can you skip the `&` (Freaking C++).

Comment: @ConnorWolf that is not what is in Christian's source. I frowned when I spotted it and I copied it from there.

Comment: @jippie - Ah, derp, Either that's the problem, or I don't know how C++ objects work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using [Arduino-Tiny](http://code.google.com/p/arduino-tiny/) with the hardware serial port (and I *think* the soft-serial port too), I think the solution should be as simple as changing your `Serial.write(intVar)` to `Serial.print(intVar)`

As far as I can tell, the `write` function seems to be a lower-level thing, that only works on strings. What I think is happening is that you're passing an int, and the tiny is treating that int as the pointer to a zero-terminated string, and is proceeding to print the contents of a random memory address until it finally hits a zero.

As usual, the solution is to [go to the source](http://code.google.com/p/arduino-tiny/source/browse/cores/tiny/Print.cpp).

It's worth noting that I'm not sure how the actual serial library (either `HardwareSerial.cpp` or `TinyDebugSerial.h` is actually involved in the build process. I suspect it's something done in a makefile or the arduino tool, but I don't see any direct reference from either of the actual serial libraries to the print library, that I believe handles the actual formatting of arguments before passing them off to the serial libraries as a set of bytes.
The whole arduino build process is very confusing, and I have not done much C++ at all, so I'm not familiar with how inheritance works in it.

Comment: I agree with your diagnosis and remedy. As for the connection between `Serial` and `Print`: `Serial` is actually an alias of `TinyDebugSerial`, which inherits from `Stream`, which inherits from `Print`. At compile time, anything in the relevant core/variant directory is compiled automatically.

Comment: @microtherion - I figured it was some weird inheritance thing, and I didn't spend that much time looking at it. I really don't know much C++ at all. I really only use C and python. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Cause**: Why are you first converting the integer to a string:

```
String myString = String(sensorValue);
```

Only to try and print the integer itself on the next line:

```
Serial.write(sensorValue);
```

**Solution**: Change the second line to:

```
Serial.write(myString);
```

And/or check of @ConnorWolf's `Serial.print();` solution works.

Another option is to:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
char myString[ 6 ] = { 0 };
utoa( sensorValue , myString , 10 };
Serial.write( myString );
```

Some Arduino functions/libraries don't work on ATtiny's, but there is no formal list which do or don't. It is pretty much a trial and error thing, hence this `utoa();`  alternative. I've successfully used utoa on a ATtiny45, 85 and 2313.

Comment: From his answer, it sounds like he tried `Serial.write(myString);`, and got a compiler error. Look at the last code-segment in the OP.

Comment: Shoot, no easy rep for me today :o(